# Is there any way to apply margin-bottom in Github profile readme?

Tags: github

I tried to apply margin-bottom, but nothing has changed.

[Here is the image where I want to have some margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNJtE.png)

here is my code without margin:

```html
<p align="left">
<a href="https://twitter.com/dikshajain46" target="blank"><img align="center" src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Twitter-1DA1F2?style=for-the-badge&logo=twitter&logoColor=white" alt="dikshajain46" height="30" width="100" /></a>&nbsp;
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/diksha-jain-35208a241/" target="blank"><img align="center" src="https://img.shields.io/badge/LinkedIn-0077B5?style=for-the-badge&logo=linkedin&logoColor=white" alt="diksha jain" height="30" width="100" /></a>&nbsp;
<a href="https://www.hackerrank.com/jdiksha394" target="blank"><img align="center" src="https://img.shields.io/badge/-Hackerrank-2EC866?style=for-the-badge&logo=HackerRank&logoColor=white" alt="@jdiksha394" height="30" width="110" /></a>&nbsp;
<a href="https://www.leetcode.com/dixa_xyz" target="blank"><img align="center" src="https://img.shields.io/badge/-LeetCode-FFA116?style=for-the-badge&logo=LeetCode&logoColor=black" alt="dixa_xyz" height="30" width="100" /></a>&nbsp;
<a href="https://codepen.io/dixa1428" target="blank"><img align="center" src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Codepen-000000?style=for-the-badge&logo=codepen&logoColor=white" alt="@dixa1428" height="30" width="100" /></a>&nbsp;
<a href="https://auth.geeksforgeeks.org/user/jdiksha394" target="blank"><img align="center" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rahuldkjain/github-profile-readme-generator/master/src/images/icons/Social/geeks-for-geeks.svg" alt="jdiksha394" height="30" width="40" /></a>&nbsp;
</p>
```

Comment: Can you share the current code of your markdown file? It will be helpful to understand better.

Comment: I have shared it.